# Remove table cell while cells from next rows fill the place

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table which each row has a fixed number of cells, by clicking on each cell it's removed.

What I want is the cells to kind of float and fill the place so the table shrinks from the end of the last row (instead of each row separately). So if the table is like:

```
A ... B ... C ... D  
E ... F ... G ... H  
I ... J ... K ... L
```

If `C` is removed the result will be like:

```
A ... B ... D ... E  
F ... G ... H ... I  
J ... K ... L
```

[**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/a1bL55rh/)

```
$('td').on('click', function() {
    $(this).remove();
   //re-arrange table
});
```

The only way I can think of is to put all tds in an array, empty the table and create a new one based on available tds. Would that be the way to go or there's a more efficient way of achieving this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I want each row to hold the same amount of cells as the original after a cell is removed, except from the last row, so cells are pushed to upper rows to fill the place.

Comment: If you are using table only as solution for formating you page, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @RikyTres no the table has nothing to do with the page layout if that's what you mean.

Comment: Ok, I was just dotting I's and crossing T's ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code to rearrange next all `tr > td` after remove `td`, this is will take only all next `tr` first `td` and move into deleted td tr section...
it will run only next all available tr times, so it would better from remap whole table after remove `td`

```js
var tbl = $('#num_tbl');
var tr = $('<tr/>');
for (var i = 1; i < 102; i++) {
  if ((i - 1) % 10 == 0) {
    tbl.append(tr);
    tr = $('<tr/>');
    if ((i - 1) / 10 % 2 == 1)
      tr.addClass('odd');
  }
  var td = $('<td/>');
  td.text(i);
  td.attr("data-num", i);
  tr.append(td);
}

$('td').on('click', function() {
  var $_thisTR = $(this).closest('tr');
  $.when($(this).remove()).then(function() {
    $_thisTR.next('tr').find('td:first').detach().appendTo($_thisTR);
    $_thisTR.next('tr').nextAll('tr').each(function(i, o) {
      $('>td:first', o).detach().appendTo($(o).prev());
      if (!$('td', o).length) {
        $(o).remove();
      }
    })
  })
});
```

```css
td {
  padding: 8px 16px;
}
tr.odd {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="num_tbl"></table>
```

Comment: So if I understand correctly, when a cell removed it takes the row, moves the cell from the beginning of next row to this and does that for the next rows as well?

Comment: the each loop is taking next `tr` first `td` and move into just previous `tr` at last.. suppose you have 10 `trs` in table and you have removed 5th tr `td` then the each loop will run only 4 time only

Answer (score 1):

If you are not forced to use tables, just use floating divs with a fixed width.

```
.table-item { float: left: width: 25%; }
```

Comment: Thanks. In the demo I generate a table, I'm working on a given table though. However I could convert the table on load to inline-block or floated elements. I rather to make it work the way it is though if not too inconvenient.